# Как заменить актуальное изображение на изображение из drawable?

Tags: java, android

Задача: программно поменять изображение.

Перепробовала множество вариантов с заменой изображения, которое есть в макете, на то, которое есть в drawable.
Также пробовала в макет добавлять изображение, которое должно заменить изображение из этого же макета. Результата это не принесло.

Один из вариантов:

```
ImageView img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_image);
```

Ошибка:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.widget.ImageView.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
```

ИЛИ (в зависимости от варианта)

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)'
```

SecondLayout.xml:

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/cafe"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:src="@drawable/cafe" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/baron"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:src="@drawable/bar" />
```

Основной class имеет OneLayout.xml

ExampleBottomSheetDialog.class имеет SecondLayout.xml

В основном class'e, когда вы нажимаете на маркер, активируется ExampleBottomSheetDialog.class:

```
public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {

ExampleBottomSheetDialog bottomSheet = new ExampleBottomSheetDialog();
bottomSheet.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "exampleBottomSheet");

// Image replacement
if (...) {
    ImageView img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cafe);
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.bar);
}
```

ExampleBottomSheetDialog.class:

```
public class ExampleBottomSheetDialog extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {
private BottomSheetListener mListener;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet_layout, container, false);

    Button button1 = v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dismiss();
        }
    });

    return v;
}

public interface BottomSheetListener {
    void onButtonClicked(String text);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    try {
        mListener = (BottomSheetListener) context;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()
                + " must implement BottomSheetListener");
    }
}
```

}

Необходимо поменять изображение cafe на bar.

Какое есть актуальное решение данной проблемы?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79269/discussion-on-question-by-inna-ahtina------).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Данные во фрагмент (в том числе `BottomSheetDialogFragment`), при его создании, передаются через аргументы - этим и воспользуемся. Передаём id ресурса нужной картинки и во фрагменте применяем к `ImageView`:

```
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    if (...)
        args.putInt("drawable", R.drawable.bar);
    ExampleBottomSheetDialog bottomSheet = new ExampleBottomSheetDialog();
    bottomSheet.setArguments(args);
    bottomSheet.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "exampleBottomSheet");
```

---

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet_layout, container, false);
    ...
    ImageView img = v.findViewById(R.id.cafe);
    int drawable = getArguments().getInt("drawable", R.drawable.default_drawable);
    img.setImageResource(drawable);
    ...
    return v;
}
```

Comment: с одним изображением работает, как быть если их больше 1?Поясню, при одной проверке `if (...)` всё работает как и должно, но стоит добавить после одного условия другое `if (...)` `if (...)`, то при клике изображение не меняется на то, которое указано внутри проверки, изображение остается прежним. В большинстве случаев отображается изображение, которое было в самой последней проверке. Тут как я понимаю, нужно чистить ImageView или что-то подобное, как в данном случае это сделать?

Comment: Там нечего чистить - до вызова `show` Ваш `ImageView` вообще не существует. Само условие не правильно составлено или входные данные для условия не верные - при каждом клике по маркеру только один нужный `if` должен сработать. И это уже другой вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Вам надо передать изображения с одного активити в дургое.
Проблема в неправильном подходе.Что-бы реализовать это вам надо

1)сконвертировать изображение в байты

```
 Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

2)Положить байты в Intent в 1 активити

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("picture", byteArray);
startActivity(intent);
```

3)Вытащить байты из интента во 2 активити и передать изобажение в `Imageview`.Вроде все

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
byte[] byteArray = extras.getByteArray("picture");

Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Comment: добавила в шапку весь связанный с этим код